# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest' in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: java, android

I am new in Java and Android. When I apply to RUN PROJECT, this message is showing. Hence I need your help about the following problem.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

This is my gradle file and i have SDK Versions 26.0.2 and 28.0.0

```
enter code here
```

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.floating_action_button_example.javacodegeeks.com.androidfloatingactionbuttonexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'`enter code here
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:design:26.0.2"
}

Answer (score 0):

It has a tricky solution. Just comment out one by one in build.gradle and try to run.Then it will works and you can easily understand where is the problem. For an example:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```